# Elements slid up in jQuery are messed up in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have created an faq section and it's fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE 8, when slid up the elements seem to lose their bottom-margin.

I have prepared a fiddle but it seems to have a different problem and even appears messed up in Chrome with multiple bottom borders showing.

I was hoping to see if anyone knew why this was happening?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vYLb/

**HTML**

```
<div id="faq-q-a">

    <div class="question-wrapper">
        <h3>This is the first question?</h3>
        <div class="answer">
           <p>Morbi et arcu eget dolor tempor volutpat. Mauris a leo dolor, vitae cursus diam. Morbi faucibus convallis rutrum. </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question-wrapper">
        <h3>This is the second question?</h3>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Morbi et arcu eget dolor tempor volutpat. Mauris a leo dolor, vitae cursus diam. Morbi faucibus convallis rutrum. </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question-wrapper">
        <h3>This is the third question</h3>
        <div class="answer">
            <p>Morbi et arcu eget dolor tempor volutpat. Mauris a leo dolor, vitae cursus diam. Morbi faucibus convallis rutrum. </p>
        </div>
   </div>    

</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#faq-q-a h3').each(function() {
    var h3 = $(this);
    answer = h3.next('.answer').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();

    h3.click(function() {
        h3.parent('.question-wrapper').toggleClass('active');

        if (h3.parent('.question-wrapper').is('.active')) {
            h3.next('.answer').slideDown('slow');
        }
        else {
            h3.next('.answer').slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#faq-q-a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 22px;
}

.question-wrapper {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
    width: 420px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}  

.question-wrapper.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#faq-q-a h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #408261;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#faq-q-a div.answer {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#faq-q-a div.answer p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial, Helvetica;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 300px;
}​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the .question-wrapper CSS:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/4vYLb/1/